# Error connecting to NetSuite Sandbox from within Eclipse

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am using Eclipse 2020-06 with NetSuite 2020.1 IDE, and getting the following error when attempting to deploy a simple SuiteScript project with just one User Event Script.

[image]

Some background on successful tasks:

- Within Eclipse, I have added a domain of XXXXXX-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com
- When adding my account to this domain within Eclipse, the username/password is accepted
- The Eclipse IDE then allows me to manage authentication type for each
  role assigned to my account in NetSuite.
- I have left each role's Authentication Type as "User Credentials"
- On the NetSuite server, I have followed the instructions for installing the SuiteCloud Development Framework (https://4583703-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_4702629975.html)

Some comments on my Eclipse Environment:

- This is a brand new Eclipse download with only NetSuite IDE added
- There is only one project in the Eclipse workspace, and that SuitScript project contains just a single auto-generated script with no modifications/references
- I've repeated this step multiple times with different projects, and always get the same error message referencing the same application id of "22804373-084A-49DC-8622-4DECD6ED07E7"

So this clearly seems to be a server-side issue.

My questions:

- This applicationId is clearly derived from the NetSuite server, any ideas where it is coming from?
- Other ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Randy

Comment: Last I checked you had to use the Mars or Kepler version of Eclipse. But, on that note, I never got this to work and switched to Brackets, before switching again to WebStorm. I don't want to deter you from Eclipse, but don't want you to go bonkers either.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I downloaded Eclipse Mars, but got the same error.  I then downloaded WebStorm... continue to get the same error of "Invalid application id: 22804373-084A-49DC-8622-4DECD6ED07E7".  This must be some sort of issue on the server side.  Ugh.

Comment: I'm getting same error bro, did you find a solution for that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try an Account Customization project instead of a SuiteApp which requires an application id

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I am actually creating Account Customization project, and still getting this error.

Comment: I have found the following article saying "NetSuite's Application Id is now required": https://support.cazoomi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004914671-NetSuite-s-Application-ID-is-now-required-for-authenticating-to-NetSuite-API.  

Perhaps the IDE's are not yet up to speed?  Not really sure.